# How to make three calls to my database without repeating myself

Tags: javascript

I am using the Parse SDK for Javascript in order to connect to my database and insert three records. My code works but I am repeating myself a lot and I was wondering if there is a smarter and better way to make those calls and insert my data without repeating code? Here is my code:

```
const Parse = require('parse/node');

Parse.initialize(
    "test",
    "test"
  );

Parse.serverURL = 'url';

const CarObject = Parse.Object.extend("Car");

const firstCar = new CarObject();
const secondCar = new CarObject();
const thirdCar = new CarObject();
firstCar.set("driver", "Sean Plott");
secondCar.set("driver", "Brad Plott");
thirdCar.set("driver", "John Davis");

firstCar.save()
    .then((result) => {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        console.info("New object was created with objectId:", result.id);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        console.error("Error message:", error.message);
    });

    secondCar.save()
    .then((result) => {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        console.info("New object was created with objectId:", result.id);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        console.error("Error message:", error.message);
    });

    thirdCar.save()
    .then((result) => {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        console.info("New object was created with objectId:", result.id);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        console.error("Error message:", error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Will there only ever be three cars?

Comment: `[firstCar, secondCar, thirdCar].forEach(car => car.save().then().catch())` Try something like this.

Comment: `await Promise.all([firstCar.save, secondCar.save,  thirdCar.save]);`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess the code can be repeated up to the oneThousandSevenHundredAndFiftyNinthCar

Comment: Then the cars need to be in an array or other similar collection, not separate variables.  Once they're in a collection, you can process them using an ordinary loop, assuming the logic is the same for every car.

Comment: You could also create a service if you will, passing an object array and success/failure callback functions

Comment: Expanding on the above to get the info's `await Promise.all([firstCar, secondCar, thirdCar].map(m => m.save().then(r => console.info("New object was created with objectId:", r.id))))`

Comment: There will be only three cars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to store the data in an array and create Object with some helper function below:

```js
const Parse = require("parse/node");

Parse.initialize("test", "test");

Parse.serverURL = "url";

const CarObject = Parse.Object.extend("Car");

function initCarObject(role, name) {
  const car = new CarObject();
  car.set(role, name);
  return car;
}

const data = [
  { role: "driver", name: "Sean Plott" },
  { role: "driver", name: "Brad Plott" },
  { role: "driver", name: "John Davis" },
];

//Promises in Parallel
function createCarParallel(data) {
  data.map(el =>
    initCarObject(el.role, el.name)
      .save()
      .then(res => console.log(res.id))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  );
}

//Promises in Series
async function createCarSeries(data) {
  for (const el of data) {
    try {
      const res = await initCarObject(el.role, el.name).save();
      console.log(res.id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}

createCarSeries(data);
createCarParallel(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Among all the possible ways to do this, I'd say :

If you want to save all your Cars one after the other :

```
for( let driver of [ "Sean Plott", "Brad Plott", "John Davis"]) {
    const car = new CarObject();
    car.set("driver", driver);
    let result;
    try{
        result = await car.save();
        console.info("New object was created with objectId:", result.id);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error("Error message:", error.message);
    }
}
console.log("All cars saved")
```

If you want to save all your cars concurrently (faster, but it hammers the DB, so only use this when you don't have too many Cars)

```
const promises = [ "Sean Plott", "Brad Plott", "John Davis" ].map( driver => {
    const car = new CarObject();
    car.set("driver", driver);
    return car.save // this is a Promise
});

try {
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log("All cars saved with ids = ", result.map( r => r.id ) );
} catch(err) {
    console.error("Error message:", error.message);
}
```

Comment: second snippet..  `return car.save`, don't forget to call it..

Comment: There's an error in your concurrent example `Promise.all(promises)` should be `Promise.all(Promises)`

Comment: @Keith `Promise.all` takes care of calling `car.save`

Comment: @IanBrindley  Unfortunately not, try->  `async function save() { console.log('save'); }  await Promise.all([save])`  You will just end up with an array with a function inside `>[f]`

Comment: @Keith I also don't think that try/catch is appropriate for handling Promise.all rejections and should be `Promise.all(Promises).catch(/* */)`

Comment: @Keith That's interesting, I'll have to test it, I assumed async/await would behave identically to the Promise

Comment: @IanBrindley  `try / catch` is fine with `async / await`, but yes if the user was not using `async / await` you would need to use the catch callback.  Also `Promise.all` doesn't behave any differently with `async/await` eg. `function save() { console.log('save'); return Promise.resolve() }; Promise.all([save]).then(r => console.log(r));`   will still return an array with a function inside.

Comment: @IanBrindley, Thanks, I fixed my code by lowercasing the variable name instead!

Comment: @Keith Since `car.save` is a Promise, I'm getting a `Promise[]`, which I pass to Promise.all... I don't think I have to call `car.save()`, do I?

Comment: If ```car.save``` is a promise, why OP need to write in this way ```car.save().then()```? He can write ```car.save.then()``` instead, right?

Answer (score 0):

This seems concise enough - pull the callbacks out into seperate functions, and loop through each car one-by-one with a `for...of` loop.

```js
const Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize("test", "test");
Parse.serverURL = 'url';

const CarObject = Parse.Object.extend("Car");

const cars = ["Sean Plott", "Brad Plott", "John Davis"].map((name) => {
  const car = new CarObject();
  car.set("driver", name);
  return car;
});

const onSuccess = (result) => {
  // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
  console.info("New object was created with objectId:", result.id);
};
const onError = (error) => {
  // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
  // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  console.error("Error message:", error.message);
};

for (const car of cars) {
  car.save()
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onError);
}
```